# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 at line 9

Tags: java

i am trying to generate random numbers in "2 d" array but i not understanding why i am facing this error?

My code:

```
package rand;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class random {
    public static void main( String [] args){
        Integer[][] arr = new Integer[2][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr[2].length; i++) 
        {
            for(int j=0; j<arr[2].length;j++)
            arr[i][j] = i;
        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    }

}
```

error at console:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>   at rand.random.main(random.java:9)

any idea???

Comment: the array is of length 2. so the index list if 0,1 and not 1,2.

Comment: [[Ljava.lang.Integer;@7a 2760f ]] it is not error it is showing array is type of integer

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing `arr[2]` while its size is `2`.

That is, one index after its size.

Arrays are 0-based.

Reference `arr[1]` instead.

Or even better, reference `arr[arr.length - 1]`.

**First for loop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr[arr.length - 1].length; i++)
```

**Nested for loop**

```
for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length;j++)
```

Comment: i have written this is this wrong plz specify: for (int i = 0; i < arr[arr.length-1]; i++)

Comment: help actually i am new in java so making mistakes.

Comment: I disagree with the first loop limit. It should be `arr.length`, not the length of the last subarray, which by the way could be inexistent if `arr.length==0`. Here it is the same, because both are of length 2, but **in the general case it won't work**, because `arr[i]` could be out of bound when you reference it in the nested loop limit.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

The error comes from an access to `arr[2]`, while only indices `0` and `1` are valid (0-based index) for an array of size 2.

### The solution

Your limits should be instead:

- `i < arr.length` in the first loop
- `j < arr[i].length` in the second loop.

### The explanation

As a general rule, access to `something[index]` requires `0 <= index < something.length`.

What's wrong in your case:

- In the first loop, you can replace my `something` by your `arr` and the index is `i`. You're defining an index `i` that is used to access `arr[i]` **without limiting it to the range of `arr`**.
- In the second loop, you can replace my `something` by your `arr[i]` and the index is `j`. You're defining an index `j` that is used to access `arr[i][j]`, but **`j` is not guaranteed to be in the range of `arr[i]`, because you define it in the range of `arr[2]`** (which by the way, does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length;j++)
        arr[i][j] = i;
    }
```

Comment: now i am having this error: [[Ljava.lang.Integer;@7a2760f, [Ljava.lang.Integer;@3af4d6b3]
???? any idea??

Answer (score 0):

In java, array index starts from 0. In your program you are trying to fetch the data from array's 3 position. while the size of array is 2. this is the reason you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. If you put 1 instead 2 in the loop. you won't face any problem.
like this

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class random
{
    public static void main( String [] args)
    {
        Integer[][] arr = new Integer[2][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr[1].length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<arr[1].length;j++)
            {
              arr[i][j] = i;
              int iData=Math.random()*(int)arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

when you will run the above program, you will get the following output.

```
[[Ljava.lang.Integer;@19821f, [Ljava.lang.Integer;@addbf1]
```

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: i am not getting correct numbers. am only getting "[[Ljava.lang.Integer;@19821f, [Ljava.lang.Integer;@addbf1]" i am trying for random number. I am facing problem at :   Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

Comment: so plz make a small help. I did search but does not getting help.